# How to get an initial CSRF token when working with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API with the Django Rest Framework. Users are still going to need to get a CSRF token to make POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE calls. What is the best practice for the user initially getting a CSRF token? I am using TokenAuthentication. So I just need to allow the API to take and username and password and send back the Token. After that I don't need the CSRF token.

Do I have to add a step that will allow them to get CSRF token using a GET method call which will return a token?

I am looking for suggestions on how to best approach this.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax does not help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an API you are just about to open a gate to process requests on your server without any session and browser. CSRF tokens are just validating form requests to make sure it's sent from your website. As far as I know it's absolutely ok to turn off CSRF protection for APIs.

You can use **[csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)** decorator for this.

Read this article to learn more about **[CSRF and Web API protection](https://mathieu.fenniak.net/is-your-web-api-susceptible-to-a-csrf-exploit/)**.

Comment: But what if we have to store the token in the cookies for remembering the user after browser restart. Once the token is stored in the cookie, we need to ensure CSRF protection.